# Finding information related to a class in intellij ide

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I find information about a class programmatically. For example, lines of code in that class, number and names of method, number of lines of code in each method, References to methods for coupling and cohesion etc.

I am trying to develop a plugin in intellij Ide.

How can I get these information from actionPreformed method?

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
    Project project = event.getProject();
    Class c = event.getClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only useful thing is using the methods contained in the class "Class". you can't really know the number of lines, however. A compiled class doesn't contain any information about the line number. You need to analyze the source file instead to obtain all the information you want to.

[Class on javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some old code I have to return the `ASTNode` at the caret position in the current editor window.

```
private ASTNode getParentNode(AnActionEvent e) {
    Editor editor = e.getData(PlatformDataKeys.EDITOR);
    PsiFile psiFile = e.getData(LangDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
    if (psiFile == null || editor == null)
        return null;

    int offset = editor.getCaretModel().getOffset();
    PsiElement elementAt = psiFile.findElementAt(offset);
    if (elementAt == null || elementAt.getParent() == null || elementAt.getParent().getNode() == null)
        return null;

    return elementAt.getParent().getNode();
}
```

Probably from the editor or the psiFile you can get more information about the source file... take a look.